# Sobre Carga de metodos Constructor en java

Tags: java, array, poo

tengo una duda hace ya un tiempo que no logro comprender , Si un constructor sirve para iniciar los atributos de una clase , por que no se crea uno solo que reciba por parametros todos los argumentos respectivos a sus Atributos , aca les muestro un ejemplo.

```
//****************** clase Estudiante
public class Estudiante
{
    private int legajo;
    private String nombre;
    private float promedio;

    public Estudiante()
    {
    }
    public Estudiante(int leg, String nom, float prom)
    {
        legajo = leg;
        nombre = nom;
        promedio = prom;
    }
    public Estudiante(int leg)  
        legajo = leg;
    }
    public int getLegajo()
    {
        return legajo;
    }
    public void setLegajo(int leg) // 
    {
        legajo = leg; //que funcion Cumple este constructor,
                      //si arriba ya se declaro 
    }
    public String getNombre()
    {
         return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nom)
    {
         nombre = nom;
    }
    public float getPromedio()
    {
         return promedio;
    }
    public void setPromediosetPromedio(float prom)
    {
         promedio = prom;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
         return "Legajo: " + legajo + "\tNombre: " + nombre + "\tPromedio: " + promedio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por default al crear una clase Java nos da un Constructor Vacío para crear instancias, y después usar los métodos set y get para los valores de los atributos.Sin embargo si creas un constructor sobrecargado ya no puedes usar el constructor por default a menos que lo declares en como en tu ejemplo, espero te sirva.

Comment: Si tienes un constructor con parámetros ya no es necesario crear getters y setters, pues prácticamente ya estás inicializando tus variables. Si deseas poner un constructor vacío puedes inicializarlas con sus getters y setters, pero tener ambas en algunos casos ya es redundante, porque con cualquiera de las dos formas solucionas el problema. Espero que te sirva de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

La sobrecarga de métodos es la creación de varios métodos con el mismo nombre, pero que se diferencia en la cantidad y tipo  de parametros y/o argumentos que recibe. En el código que muestras hay tres métodos constructores y la diferencia entre ellos como puedes notar, simplemente está en la cantidad de parametros que recibe. En el primer Constructor no recibe parametros, en el segundo recibe tres parametros de tipo int, String y float respectivamente y en el tercero solo recibe un argumento que es un int.

Todo esto tiene como principal utilidad que podemos instanciar de tres maneras distintas:

Primera Forma:

```
Estudiante est = new Estudiante(); //Sin parametros
```

Segunda Forma:

```
Estudiante est = new Estudiante(1, 'Luis Ortega', 6.5f);  //Con 3 parametros
```

Tercera Forma:

```
Estudiante est = new Estudiante(1); //Con un solo parametro, que corresponde a int leg
```

Answer (score 0):

Qué constructores y métodos se definen son decisiones de diseño y como tales dependerán completamente de como se estructure la aplicación, de las técnicas de diseño (por ejemplo el *builder pattern*) e incluso de preferencias personales y estilo de código. No hay una respuesta "correcta".

Puedes tener atributos que sean desconocidos en el momento de instanciar la clase. Puedes tener atributos que varíen durante la vida de la instancia (con lo cual necesitarás operaciones para cambiar esos valores y no bastarán con pasar esos valores via constructores). Puedes tener una clase con 20 atributos, e invocar a un constructor con 20 parámetros hace muy difícil leer el código y muy fácil pasar un parámetro en vez de otro.

Un concepto interesante es el de la *inmutabilidad*; si hay atributos que no van a cambiar durante la vida de la instancia (por ejemplo un identificador) ayuda que solo se puedan asignar mediante el constructor. Pero los atributos inmutables son muy raros, y las ventajas que proporciona esta restricción del acceso muy limitados.

Además, el uso de beans (una clase con un constructor sin parámetros, y con *setters* y *getters*) está muy extendido porque ayuda a automatizar muchos procesos (por ejemplo, con JPA o Hibernate defines un bean y se puede asociar directamente un objeto con un registro de una tabla). Si usas frameworks que necesitan beans (y hay muchísimos), dejas el control de qué atributos son inmutables o no a las capas superiores de la aplicación, y dejas que tu *bean* sea "tonto" (todo lo más con validaciones para asegurar que los valores sean coherentes).